# Display mouse position in Silverlight 5, MVVM

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm, mousemove

For the record: I'm new to Silverlight and XAML.

I'm trying to simply display the mouse coordinates relative in my canvas (or any other element).
After reading a lot on the subject, unfortunantly I havn't figured this our yet.
My Silverlight 5 project uses MVVM with Caliburn micro.

How can this be done?
Would Appreciate help on implementing this.

Thanks,
Guy.

Answer (score 3):

You need to be a little more specific with what control you're trying to get this with, but have you tried wiring something up to the `MouseMove` event? Like `MouseMove="Handle_MouseMove"`

```
public void Handle_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs args) 
{
    mouseVerticalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).Y;
    mouseHorizontalPosition = args.GetPosition(null).X;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?

If you want this to happen on the entire canvas, you can instead wire it up to [PointerMoved](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.pointermoved)

See [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx). This can get you the `X` and `Y` position and it can be used with the `MouseUp`, `MouseDown`, and `MouseMove` events.

Comment: How can this be done without using the code-behind? (Using MVVM)
I'm using Caliburn.Micro, but I didn't find a way to bind the MouseMove event function to the ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

To complete tnw Answer : You have to [start mouse capture on object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.uielement.capturemouse%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) : `MyElement.CaptureMouse()`

In the handler method, you can use [GetPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/cc190492%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) on [MouseEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.input.mouseeventargs%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) with an UIElement in parameter for relative coordinates...

```
public void Handle_MouseMove(object e, MouseEventArgs f)
{
     var point = f.GetPosition(MyElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to catch the mouse click event and there are some event handlers you can use it to capture the position.

```
private void CadLayoutRoot_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
                double point1 = e.GetPosition(bitmapCadView.UIElement).X;
                double point2 = e.GetPosition(bitmapCadView.UIElement).Y;
    }
```